# looping thru div ids to display somewhere else

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have a div using the id of Location like so:

```
<div id="Weymouth">
    <ul style="padding: 4px 6px;">
        <li>
            <div style="float:left;padding: 0 0 0 0; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">May 21st</div>
            <div style="float:right;padding: 0 0 0 0; text-align: right;">5PM - 7:30PM</div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
            <div style="float:left;padding: 0 0 0 0; text-align: left;">Weymouth Liquor Store</div>
            <div style="float:right;padding: 0 0 0 0; text-align: right;"><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Andover,+MA//@42.6495835,-71.166032,12z/data=!4m8!4m7!1m5!1m1!1s0x89e308597f9a4cf5:0x28f59c5c00d57256!2m2!1d-71.1367953!2d42.6583356!1m0" class="amstel" target="_blank">Directions</a></div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="Marshfield">
    <ul style="padding: 4px 6px;">
        <li>
            <div style="float:left;padding: 0 0 0 0; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">May 10th</div>
            <div style="float:right;padding: 0 0 0 0; text-align: right;">6PM - 8PM</div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
            <div style="float:left;padding: 0 0 0 0; text-align: left;">Marshfield Liquor Store</div>
            <div style="float:right;padding: 0 0 0 0; text-align: right;"><a href="" class="amstel">Directions</a></div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and i will have 20 of these locations.  I want to display them in another section of the webpage:  I have it working by calling each of the 20 locations like so:

```
var weymouth = document.getElementById('Weymouth').innerHTML;
var marshfield = document.getElementById('Marshfield').innerHTML;  (do this for all 20 locations)
```

and then call it in a ul li to display it a little differently:

```
<ul>
    <li class="alt">
        <div style="padding: 0 0 0 0; text-align: left;">
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">document.write(marshfield);</script>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="alt">
        <div style="padding: 0 0 0 0; text-align: left;">
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">document.write(weymouth);</script>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

using the same id (I want to rename to Location) and append a _1 through _20 to each location...how do I put this in a loop and display without having tomake 20 variables and 20 li's to display?

---

appending to this post with updated code that is still not working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated:
   Here's my javascript:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var target = document.querySelector('#target'), // get a reference to empty UL, target
        divs = ['Andover', 'Westford', 'Burlington', 'Boston', 'Weymouth', 'Marshfield'];
        //add ids of the divs that you want to copy to this array

        divs.forEach(function (v) { //iterate over ids array, and repeat below process for each id
            var el = document.querySelector('#' + v).cloneNode(true); //copy the div with "v" id
            var li = document.createElement('li') //create a new list item in memory
            li.className = 'alt'; //set css class name of new list item
            li.appendChild(el); // add the copied div to list item
            target.appendChild(li); //finally add the new list item to your target.
        });
    </script>

And here is my HTML:

        <div class="locations">
        <div class="headline">Burger Truck Locations</div>
             <ul id="target"></ul>
        </div>

 It is not displaying anything.  Need help.
```

Comment: `document.write` isn't a great idea. Use `innerHTML` instead. I'd use a common class on your ID divs. And for the love of Pete Sake, get all those styles out of your HTML!

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to copy some `<div>` to a `<ul>`, you can do following

```
<!-- create an empty <ul> in HTML to copy your div's into -->
<ul id="target"></ul>
```

and after your `<ul>` and `<div>`, run this script

```
var target = document.querySelector('#target'), // get a reference to empty UL, target
divs = ['Weymouth', 'Marshfield'];
//add ids of the divs that you want to copy to this array

divs.forEach(function (v) { //iterate over ids array, and repeat below process for each id
   var el = document.querySelector('#' + v).cloneNode(true); //copy the div with "v" id
   var li = document.createElement('li') //create a new list item in memory
   li.className = 'alt'; //set css class name of new list item
   li.appendChild(el); // add the copied div to list item
   target.appendChild(li); //finally add the new list item to your target.
});
```

As a side note, you should use CSS classes instead of inline styles, and avoid `document.write`

Comment: sorry i am new to this, so I apologize for the styles in the line items.  But are you saying I should make a ul (<ul id="target"></ul>) and then put a <div> inside of that?  Then, how do I display it if I do not use document.write?

Comment: you create HTML text or DOM elements (the answer demonstrates how) and inset them in your required element (`target` in answer). The bit about CSS styles/class is that instead of writing `style="padding: 4px 6px;"` inline, you could create a class, e.g., `.padd{padding: 4px 6px;}` and apply the class to your ul like `<ul class="padd">` instead of `<ul style="padding: 4px 6px;">`

Comment: that is not working.  displaying nothing.  I am going to display what i have now with your edits in your original post.

Comment: never mind.  was missing a closing character on script.  thank you for the help.